# GWT CellTable and Editors framework

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable, gwt-editors

In order to do not duplicate code, I've decided some time ago, to refactor my views towards usage of editors framework. Currently, each view is editor which contains set of other editors. For example "Person details" view contains editors such as "person address", "person image", "person description" and so on. Each of these editors contains some set of standard GWT widgets along with logic required to instantiate and display these widgets.

Now, I'd like to reuse some of these components in "persons list" view. So, I'd like to have a table with rows representing persons - one row - one person. Each row should contain for example: person name, surname, image (editor), short description (editor).

Is it possible to do so using GWT CellTable? As I browsed official and non-official documentation, it is easy to notice that it is mainly designed to work with HTML code, rather than widgets.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use an `Editor` (or any widget) inside a `CellTable`.

Some options for reusing views when using `CellTable` are to:

- use `SafeHtmlTemplates`
- create a PersonAddressCell, PersonImageCell, etc..
- create a reusable PersonalDetailsTable by extending CellTable

[SafeHtmlTemplates Java Doc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/client/SafeHtmlTemplates.html)